# javaScript parseFloat is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsefloat

parseFloat is not working in our function

There are so many answers abouth this issue but any of them are not satisfying for me.

Please see code:

```
 var kasatoplam = $('.kasatoplam');

 function fiyatTopla() {
    var eklenen = $('.adisyon .adisyontable .adsiyonTableUrunler').length;
    var urunfiyatlari = [];
    $('.adisyon .adisyontable .adsiyonTableUrunler').each(function () {
        var urunfiyat = $(this).find('.urunFiyati').text()
        urunfiyatlari.push(parseFloat(urunfiyat))
    });
    console.log(urunfiyatlari);
    var toplamfiyat = 0;
    for(i=0; i<=urunfiyatlari.length; i++){
        toplamfiyat += urunfiyatlari[i]<<0;
    }
    kasatoplam.html(toplamfiyat);
}
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: Please put together a jsFidde or snippet demonstrating the behaviour you have described.

Comment: also, there is an error in your code, you should be iterating to `< urunfiyatlari.length`

Comment: *"parseFloat is not working"*: I think it is safer to assume that `parseFloat` works, but that you misunderstand something about your code, which you have not provided in full. Please provide the relevant part of the HTML as well.

Comment: It's more likely that `urunfiyat` is not returning what you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
   `var urunfiyat = $(this).find('.urunFiyati').text()
    urunfiyatlari.push(parseFloat(urunfiyat))`
```

What is the failure mode for parseFloat?  Is it throwing an exception or just not yielding the values you expected?  It would help to know.

In any case, it seems that the contents of  `urunfiyat` must be the problem.  Have you stepped through the code with the debugger and seen what kind of text values you are getting from

```
` $(this).find('.urunFiyati').text()'    ?
```

Perhaps you are getting nothing undefined or empty string or perhaps the string needs a little processing before it is passed to parseFloat